# Get URL param/segments conditionally (JS/jQuery)

Tags: jquery, parsing, url, parameters, get

I'm using an external jQuery url parsing library http://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser to grab url segments for GET. The URL's i'm working with include one of two formats:

```
http://example.com/#name
or 
http://example.com/?name=name
```

Depending on the url im getting fed back, I want to use the url parsing library to construct a string. Either the hash tag value or the value of name. I'm running into an issue that I can't really query for an empty value using this library or I haven't found out how. Or I want to be able to figure out the URL format first. If I try to query for a url segment that it can't find, my application breaks. Any hints?

```
using http://example.com/?name=name

var url_anchor = jQuery.url.attr("anchor");
var url_query_name = jQuery.url.param("name");
if(url_anchor.length == 0){alert("The url anchor is: " + url_anchor)};
```

i'm expecting, obviously wrongly expecting :), the above to return NULL or Undefined but nothing happens.

Comment: Is it possible that url_anchor.length will be 1 if it is empty?

Comment: never thought about that, i'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to get "name" if url is passed in either format?

```
var param = jQuery.url.attr("anchor") ? jQuery.url.attr("anchor") : jQuery.url.param("name");
```